# Making box in latex for paragraphs

Tags: box

I want to make a document of question-answers in a4 paper.

In this writing, I want to write answer in a box.

Initially used `\begin{tcolorbox} ... \end{tcolorbox}` which makes boxes, with curved corners, and gray background.

But, I wanted to do very simple box.

I saw many other commands for boxes, such as `\fbox{}`, or some commands in which we have to specify the size of the box etc.

**Q.** How can we make a box which is like simplest version of box appearing from `\begin{tcolorbox} ... \end{tcolorbox}`?

Comment: it would be hellpful to have a hand sketch of the desired output

Comment: You could define your own tcolorbox with a white background and sharp corners: 
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback  = white,sharp corners}

Comment: The bigger question is whether or not you want this box to be breakable across the page boundary. If not, the solutions will be far simpler (and even not require any packages).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!